# SQL "Incorrect Syntax near 'IF' - cannot figure out issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I can't get rid of "Incorrect Syntax near 'IF'

have made several attempts with CASE and IF Else statements using begin and end.

First IF on second line has error: Incorrect Syntax near 'IF'

What am I missing ?!!!

Thanks, John

snippet of select long query.

```
CASE when (pt.PRE_POST_MODE = NULL) then
/*Error ->*/IF (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, extra.END_DATE)) != null)
                begin
                    if (IsDate(rc.START_DATE)= 1) 
                        begin
                            select (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, extra.START_DATE)))
                        end
                    else if  (CONVERT(date, rc.START_DATE) < CONVERT(date, sh.SAIL_DATE_FROM))  
                        begin
                            select 'PRE'
                        end
                    end

                    if (IsDate(extra.END_DATE) = 1)
                    begin
                        if (IsDate(rc.START_DATE) = 1) 
                            begin
                                select CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE,extra.START_DATE))
                                --WHEN CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, rc.START_DATE)) AS DATE) >= CAST(sh.SAIL_DATE_TO AS DATE) THEN 'POST'
                                if CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, rc.START_DATE)) >= sh.SAIL_DATE_TO  
                                begin
                                    select 'POST'
                                end
                            end
                    end

           ELSE 
              SELECT pt.PRE_POST_MODE

        as PRE_POST_MODE,
```

First IF on second line has error: Incorrect Syntax near 'IF'

[image]

thank you !

s://i.stack.imgur.com/7maMA.png

Comment: This is just not SQL Server syntax.  You don't have `IF` statements in the middle of a query.    You don't use `CASE` for control flow.

Comment: As gordon said, `CASE` are for conditional expresions, not control flow.

Comment: And `IF` is for control flow, not for expressions inside select statements.

Comment: As others are pointing out, there are confusions about CASE and IF statements in your code. I suggest you instead explain what is your goal and what you are going to achieve. That way you might get better help.

Comment: Also pt.PRE_POST_MODE = NULL won't work (same as != null), you should use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use case instead

```
CASE when (pt.PRE_POST_MODE = NULL) then
case when (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, extra.END_DATE)) != null)
 then (case when (IsDate(rc.START_DATE)= 1) then (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, extra.START_DATE))) 
        when (CONVERT(date, rc.START_DATE) < CONVERT(date, sh.SAIL_DATE_FROM)) then 'PRE' end)
when  (IsDate(extra.END_DATE) = 1) then (case when (IsDate(rc.START_DATE) = 1)  then CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE,extra.START_DATE)) 
                                case when CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, rc.START_DATE)) >= sh.SAIL_DATE_TO  then 'POST' else '' end)  end)
           ELSE 
              pt.PRE_POST_MODE end)
              end

        as PRE_POST_MODE
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi (and Gordon, Juan, Hatchet, et al) for explaining CASE is for conditional expresions and IF is for flow control

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as others already mentioned, IF is a control flow statement, can't be used inside a select statement.

However, you can use IIF function to achieve this result. You will be able to write the same expression using IIF, however, the result will be way too complex, I would look for other solution.

This link explains the IIF expresion:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213574.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As If can't be used alike above statement you posted, You can use Nested Case.

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2016/05/nested-case-statement-in-sql-server_15.html?m=1